# batch file loops once again at the end with nothing in variable

Tags: batch-file

having an issue with a batch file which i would use in front of vagrant provisioning (merging files into an install-script to perform installation depending on user input) which looks like this:

```
@echo off
copy %CD%\Vagrantfile_base %CD%\Vagrantfile
echo Vagrant Provisionierung
echo 1 - nodejs
echo 2 - Nginx
echo 3 - Qt
echo 4 - Git
echo 5 - gcc
echo a - Alle vorgenannte Software
set /p choice=Mittels Zahlen durch Komma getrennt angeben, was installiert werden soll (Bspw. 1,2,3):
for %%i in (%choice%) do (
    if "%%i"=="1" call :nodejs_install
    if "%%i"=="2" call :nginx_install
    if "%%i"=="3" call :qt_install
    if "%%i"=="4" call :git_install
    if "%%i"=="5" call :gcc_install
    if "%%i"=="a" call :all_install
)
:nodejs_install
copy /b %CD%\software.sh+%CD%\software\nodejs_install.sh software.sh
PAUSE
goto :EOF
:nginx_install
copy /b %CD%\software.sh+%CD%\software\nginx_install.sh software.sh
PAUSE
goto :EOF
:qt_install
copy /b %CD%\software.sh+%CD%\software\qt_install.sh software.sh
PAUSE
goto :EOF
:git_install
copy /b %CD%\software.sh+%CD%\software\git_install.sh software.sh
PAUSE
goto :EOF
:gcc_install
copy /b %CD%\software.sh+%CD%\software\gcc_install.sh software.sh
PAUSE
goto :EOF
:all_install
call :nodejs_install
call :nginx_install
call :qt_install
call :git_install
call :gcc_install
PAUSE
goto :EOF
PAUSE
```

So when i execute the script it always calls the nodejs_install at the end even if i didnt choose it and i dunno why.

When i add an echo for the i it is empty shown.

Searching for very long but didnt found anything.

Maybe someone has an answer and/or fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Batch does not have true subroutines; if you do not protect the entry point of a subroutine with a `GOTO` to get around it, it will "fall through" into the routine. You need a `GOTO :EOF` after the `)` and before the `:nodejs_install`.